# Import ms sql database data in excel file using python

Tags: python, sql-server, excel, import

I am trying to import ms sql database data in excel file using python. I am not data getting in proper order in excel sheet. e.g it is showing column 1 data then column 3 then column 2 and then column 4 and so on.
I am using the following script:

```
import pyodbc
import csv
connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                  "Server=MS-DC-06,49208;"
                  "Database=****;"
                  "uid=**;pwd=***")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select top 10 * from Api_NotificationEntry")
data=cursor.fetchall()
for col in data:
    with open('dataTester.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
      a= csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
      a.writerow({col[0],col[1]})
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

It should show data like this:

```
10 2689 
11 2689 
12 2689 
13 2689 
14 2689 
15 2689 
16 2689 
8 2673 
17 2689 
19 3083
```

But it is showing like below in excel sheet:

```
Col1    Col2
65509   
10  
2689    
65509   
10  
2689    
65509   
2689    10
2689    65509
6218    65509
2689    10
2689    65509
6218    65509
2689    10
2689    11
2689    12
2689    13
2689    14
2689    15
16  2689
8   2673
17  2689
3083    19
```

[This is how it looks like in excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWsn3.png)

[This is how it looks like in notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyk81.png)

Comment: How the data looks like, when you open it with TextEditor? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: You are opening the file and creating the csv writer for every row of the data

Comment: @Vityata I have added screenshot in the question.

Comment: @FujiApple Yes I want it in excel, what other option can be?

Comment: @KhurramRaftaz - open it in Notepad, not with Excel.

Comment: @Vityata Even in notepad, it is showing the result in same order/format. I have added screenshot for that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting data from the database I am filtering them using python script,

```
a.writerow({col[0],col[1]})
```

which is not writing data in correct sequence in the csv file, so solution is to get filtered data from the database using sql query, instead filtering it in python script. This has resolved the issue.